# Submit form validation, refreshes page and fails to proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML;

```
<form data-test="loginForm-container" novalidate="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="css-o5d3v1 e1ovefus2">
        <div data-test="guestForm-email-wrapper" class="e1ovefus1 css-yjv4po e1eu3ser1">
            <div class="css-gg4vpm e1eu3ser4">
                <label for="guestForm-email" id="guestForm-email-label" data-test="input-label" class="css-1k1vx4d e1eu3ser5">Email Address*</label>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1tpy6sb e1eu3ser7">
                <input data-test="guestForm-email" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" id="guestForm-email" type="email" name="email" required="" aria-labelledby="guestForm-email-label" class="css-15uq4zo e1eu3ser9 error" value="" aria-describedby="guestForm-email-error">
            </div><span data-test="input-error" id="guestForm-email-error" role="alert" class="css-mf5akt e1eu3ser0">Please enter email address</span></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" data-test="guestForm-submitButton" class="e1ovefus0 css-1wqqz58 e1y6awi20"><span>Continue as Guest</span></button>
</form>
```

I tried the following;

```
$("button[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
    $('[data-test="loginForm-container"] input[required]').each(function () {
        var hasValue = $(this).val().length;
        var hasRequired = $(this).prop('required');
        var inputClass = '#error-' + $(this).attr('name');

        function validator() 
        {
            if (hasValue == 0) 
            {
                console.log('Step 1');
                $(inputClass).show();
                $(this).addClass('error');
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                console.log('Step 2');
                $(inputClass).hide();
                $(this).removeClass('error');
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (validator() == true) {
            console.log('Form Submitted');
            $('[data-test="loginForm-container"]').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

When I click the button 'continue as guest', it prints out Step 1, Step 2, Form Submitted. It then refreshes the page as if it failed to validate, which it shouldn't just refresh the page, it should go onto the next page.

Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: tell us what you want to do?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah, I want it to submit and proceed to next page without it refreshing back to its original blank state.

Comment: Your `form` doesn't have a defined `action`.  How does it know what the "next" page is?

Comment: You need an action property ! Or you can use window.location.replace("url...") if this is a variable destination

Comment: when `action` property is empty, the page submitted to the same URL with HttpPost method

Answer (score 1):

In order for a `form` submission to `post` to anywhere but the current page, you need to put the destination URL in the form's `action` attribute.

Comment: how does it work then when I do not use code and do it manually?

Comment: @Andrew You mean HTML is  harcoded and you can only change Javascript ? plz explain that

Answer (score 1):

it uses React
so this code will work with you inshaAllah

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="guestForm-email"]')[0];
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="guestForm-submitButton"]')[0];
var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, 'asdfsadf@asdf.com');
var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
btn.click()
```

Comment: There is no such thing as #mainform so it does not work. It does not have an id. I cannot change the HTML

Comment: ya but in my case I can't add an id.

Comment: I also get Step 1 when I do "$("#guestForm-email").val("test@gmail.com")"

is there another way to add the value?

Comment: I put ur code, enter it into console, then I do "$("#guestForm-email").val("test@gmail.com")" and enter it into console, now the textfield has the value, and when i click 'continue as guest' it just prints step 1

Comment: check the discussion room please

Comment: THIS IS ANSWER! SALUTE!